# SqlCeException NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I'm using Sql Compact Edition.

I have this table:

TABLE "Set": [PK:IdSet (int), IdProject (int),IdSetState(int),IdPriority(int),NumSet(int),Unit(nchar),NumDisc(int)]

And using NUnit testing.

this is my test method:

```
[Test]
        public void Can_add_Set()
        {
            var set = new Set { IdProject = 2, IdSetState = 2, NumDisc = 1, IdPriority = 3, NumSet = 100};
            setRepository.AddSet(set);
        }
```

this is my method to insert a Set:

```
public void AddSet(Set set) 
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateSessionBuilder.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(set);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

This is the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="AdminProject"
                   namespace="AdminProject.Business.Entity">

  <class name="Set">
    <id name="IdSet">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="IdProject" />
    <property name="IdSetState" />
    <property name="IdPriority" />
    <property name="Unit" />
    <property name="NumDisc" />
    <property name="NumSet" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

when the session.save(set); occurs this error:

User code not control SqlCeException

Failed to parse the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Set ]

What could be this???

Answer (score 0):

you dont specify the table so nhibernate takes `Set` as the tablename. `Set` is a reserved word in most datasbases. You can try to escape it

```
<class name="Set" table="`Set`">
```

i'm not sure if i used the correct backticks though